# Cannot start Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

I am getting very frustrated with this problem with Eclipse.  I have had it many times, and quite frankly I think Eclipse is garbage.  But since I do all of my Android development there, there are no other alternative IDE's.  Here is my problem: I cannot start Eclipse.  I changed absolutely nothing, and all of a sudden the `.log` file in `.metadata` throws the following stack trace error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-11-16 15:07:22.032
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.processHierarchy(E4Workbench.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.init(E4Workbench.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.<init>(E4Workbench.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I don't know what to do!  I have no .snap file anywhere.  What else can I try???

Thank you all for your help,
Igor

Comment: Did you change / update your Java version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I occasionally have this issue as well, and it is indeed frustrating. What fixes it for me is to go into my eclipse workspace: `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins` and start deleting stuff. Most of the things in here are auto-generated; settings etc. I think you can keep `org.eclipse.core.resources` (that's where a lot of your own user settings area).

Unfortunately, this makes the workspace forget what projects you were working on, so you have to re-add them, but for me this isn't a big deal because I store them elsewhere on my filesystem.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will try that next time.  However, all of a sudden Eclipse just started up for me, without me deleting or changing anything.  This just proves how retarded the whole Eclipse software stack is.  It gets worse year after year...

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. Even after remove everything from `/.metadata/.plugins` Eclipse wont start.